# get data from URL XML with python and xmltodict

Tags: python, xml, api, xml-parsing, xmltodict

I'm trying in python2.7 with xmltodict ext.  get data from app engine API (XML type). 
Got no idea of how doing that... 
I tried to do so with local XML (I download it from source url) with success
my local code look like this:

```
import xmltodict

document = open("my local path\API_GETDATA.xml", "r")

read_doc = document.read()

xml_doc = xmltodict.parse(read_doc)

for i in xml_doc:

    print (xml_doc[i])

    i=i+1
```

and my result is printing all XML fields.

How can I make it work on url? Is there any other thing I miss?

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 4):

Use the python library [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

Install with `pip install requests` and use like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("url")

xmltodict.parse(r.content)
```

Comment: i'm getting error msg :

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\xmltodict-0.10.2\tttt.py", line 18, in 
<module>

   xmltodict.parse(r.content)

  File "C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\xmltodict-0.10.2\xmltodict.py", line 311, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0

Comment: It seems like either the XML is not proper XML or some other XML parsing problem. To debug this write the following before the parse line: `open("out.txt", "wb").write(r.content)` and upload the out.txt file to pastebin.com and post it here. I will take a look at it.